# Android: add custom fonts to system

Tags: android, fonts

I know how to use custom font in an app, but what I want to do is adding custom fonts system-wide, just like adding a new font on Windows. If there's no official way, which module of android source code should I read? I have to change android source code and build it to support custom fonts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are steps to add custom font into Android build-in system:

- Copy custom font .ttf into frameworks/base/data/fonts
- Modify frameworks/base/data/fonts/Android.mk 
  Add your custom font into list of 'font_src_files'

  font_src_files := 
  Roboto-Regular.ttf 
  ....
  AndroidClock_Solid.ttf 
  <custom_font>.ttf \
- Modify frameworks/base/data/fonts/fonts.mk 
  Add your custom font into list of PRODUCT_PACKAGES

  PRODUCT_PACKAGES := 
  DroidSansFallback.ttf 
  ...
  AndroidClock_Solid.ttf 
  <custom_font>.ttf \
- Rebuild 
  **NOTE:** Check if your custom font exists in out/target/product/generic/system/fonts or not. If yes, your custom font have already included in system. If no, recheck your modification.

Comment: Great answer. Don't forget to edit the xml files as required.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on Android 5.1.1 Lollipop.

[Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707708/nguyen)'s answer supported me, but only to some extent. So I have to edit `fonts.xml` and `fallback_fonts.xml` files (as commented by [Chef Pharaoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/679550/chef-pharaoh)).

- First do the steps [Nguyen explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016471/4132380).
- Add following lines in `fonts.xml` towards the end of the `<familyset>` element.

```xml
<family>
    <font weight="400" style="normal"><custom_font>.ttf</font>
</family>
```

- Add following lines in `fallback_fonts.xml` towards the end of the `<familyset>` element.

```xml
<family>
    <fileset>
        <file><custom_font>.ttf</file>
    </fileset>
</family>
```

(replace `<custom_font>` with your custom font name)

I found this [link](http://www.jianshu.com/p/eaf21915592f) a bit helpful, and it is in Chinese.

FYR following note is about the file `fallback_fonts.xml`

> **NOTE**: this file is the legacy format, for compatibility with apps. The new,
>       more flexible format is fonts.xml. Please keep the two in sync until the legacy
>       format can be fully removed.

Answer (score 1):

Download **Helvetica.ttf** file ,copy this file into **assets** folder and use this code.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helvetica.ttf");

    your_textview_id.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: where to download Helvetica.ttf? I'm using this way, but crashed.

Comment: check this link for downloading Helvetica.ttf file http://www.4shared.com/get/iz-q8io5/helvetica.html