# add new font to AOSP build

Tags: fonts, android-source, building

I want change the default font in my AOSP GSI builds. I have added them in /extrnal like the standard Roboto font. I have added them in /framworks/base/data/data/font.xml

But they are still not in the system.img

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vendor_overlay system and add the .ttf prebuilt file and copy it to `$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_SYSTEM)/fonts/` using `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES`.
You will also need to modify the fonts.xml to include the changes and build the overlay package as well.

Please check these as a reference point from AOSIP Project since the answer is a bit broad:

https://github.com/AOSiP/platform_vendor_overlay/tree/eleven/fonts

https://github.com/AOSiP/platform_vendor_overlay/blob/eleven/fonts.mk

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. I'm building GSI, not a rom. So vendor files will be ignored

Comment: @harvey186 The vendor_overlay is just the name of the repository here. You just have to take reference from it. You will have to define a separate .mk for it and include it  for build.
vendor_overlay here is just customisations on top of aosp tree, so this is nothing to do with /vendor partition as such, especially the fonts. This is a starting point for you.

Comment: Yes, I have done all this, when building, the overlays are found/proofed. But in final GSI none of the overlays/fonts are in system.img

Comment: I also have saved all in frameworks/base/packages/overlays. With same result. No fonts in system.img

Comment: Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627806/android-add-custom-fonts-to-system

Comment: Could you tell me how I can change the default font ? I have added my fonts in /frameworks/base/data/fonts/fonts.xml on first place. but Roboto is still the default font set. Thx